# Gravitational field on infinite cylinder of surface r($\theta$)

Tags: calculus, vectors, physics

Imagine an object defined in cylindrical coordinates whose surface is defined as $r(\theta)$.  The "cylinder" is infinite (for purposes of this of problem), so the mass per cross sectional area is a constant $\sigma$.  The radius continuously increases from $\theta = 0$, where the radius is $r = r_0 > 0$ to $\theta = 2\pi$ (an [involute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involute) $r(\theta) = r_0\sqrt{1+\theta^2}$ is an example of a function that meets these requirements). Placing a small object at $\theta = 2\pi$, imagine the object slides down along the surface from $2\pi$ to $0$, under influence of gravity alone.  What function $r(\theta)$ would cause the acceleration of the small object to be uniform (constant) from $\theta = 0$ to $\theta = 2\pi$?

1. The simple form would be to simply assume gravity pulls towards $(0,0)$, regardless of $r(\theta)$.
2. The more complex form would be to use [Newton's law of universal gravitation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_universal_gravitation). $F = \frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}$.
3. An even more complex form would have $\theta$ extend past $2\pi$, to any arbitrary value (i.e. a car on top of a mountain sliding down into a tunnel around and around and around the world) - defined by the road function ($r_1(\theta)$) and a top of tunnel function ($r_2(\theta)$). In this form, the minimum r should be 0, where the two functions would intersect.

I've self [nerd sniped](https://xkcd.com/356/) on this and need additional help.

Comment: Your first two proposals won't work.  There is no way that gravity simply pulls toward the center all the time.  The configuration is just too complicated.  Also, the $1/r^2$ law only applies in full 3D space.

Comment: If the cylinder was perfectly smooth, it would have constant acceleration of 0 around the surface, and pull towards (0,0).  Now putting an infinitesimally shallow ramp (constant angle) around the surface would have similar effects.  This is the intent of the first model - shallow ramps around the world.

Comment: The second one goes beyond the first model - by running along with 3D space at the center of a near-infinite - ignoring edge effects essentially - cylinder.  As such, a sliver of cross section of the cylinder could be compounded and simplified to a formula, used in the double integration.  At least, that was the way I thought of handling it.

Comment: Your first proposal is fine: let $r(\theta)=R - \varepsilon \theta$ for $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$, some large $R$, and some small $\varepsilon$.  Then the force of gravity pulls toward the origin to a first approximation, with strength independent of $\theta$, and the object will "slide" toward larger $\theta$ due to the local slope.

Comment: @Mark 2D problem? Not  clear  to me what  you want or mean by acceleration...Radial? Tangential? Coreolis? Do you want is equation of a spiral so that the vector sum of some accelerations is constant?

Comment: Tangential force is constant.  It is intended as a 2D problem as well.